# Is iOS (Safari, Chrome) capable of playing background videos, HTML 5 or YouTube?

Tags: background, youtube, html5-canvas, html5-video, fullscreen

Just building a website and playing youtube videos in the background (fullscreen) and having a content as a overlay on top of it and it is built also in responsive design. Video does not play on the iOS it has just background color that I specified in CSS. Is there a way at all that iOS is capable of playing background videos anyhow?

Comment: What video formats are you providing? Did you check that Safari can play the video format? How are you playing the video? Please share the code you are having problems with and if possible a fiddle.

Comment: I used this plugin, I know how to work with HTML 5 videos and players but this is something else, having a website content while playing video on the background, it works but not on the iOS and I would like to know if this or anything exists in the world that works also on iOS, I dont want play button on the background in iOS, I want video to be playing and thats my question if that something like that exists....here is the link: http://pupunzi.com/#mb.components/mb.YTPlayer/YTPlayer.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Most effective method for video as background in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26571806/most-effective-method-for-video-as-background-in-ios)