# Most effective method for video as background in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, user-interface, video

Perhaps you have noticed one of the latest trend in iOS-apps: Using videos as backgrounds - mainly at login- or "first launch" screens. Yesterday I attempted to mimic this with a very simple test project (only one view controller) and I am pleased with the results except for the **performance**. When trying it out in the iOS Simulator (on a simulated iPhone 6) the **CPU usage** fluctuates between **70-110%**. This seems very unreasonable for a simple login-screen.

This is what it looks like in action:
http://oi57.tinypic.com/nqqntv.jpg

The question is then: *Is there a more CPU-effective way to achieve this? How are the apps like Vine, Spotify and Instagram doing this?*

Before you answer; the method I used was a full-HD video played back using MPMoviePlayerController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // find movie file
    NSString *moviePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"arenaVideo" ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath];

    // load movie
    self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
    self.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    self.moviePlayer.view.frame = self.view.frame;
    self.moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
    [self.view addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:self.moviePlayer.view];
    [self.moviePlayer play];

    // loop movie
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                             selector: @selector(replayMovie:)
                                                 name: MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object: self.moviePlayer];
}

#pragma mark - Helper methods

-(void)replayMovie:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [self.moviePlayer play];
}
```

Of course the edges of the video could have been trimmed so that the resolution would be something more along the lines of say 700x1080 instead of 1920x1080 but would that have made a huge difference in performance? Or should I compress the video with a certain format and settings to achieve optimal performance? Maybe there is an entirely alternate approach to this?

Actually I tried using GIFs as described in this article: https://medium.com/swift-programming/ios-make-an-awesome-video-background-view-objective-c-swift-318e1d71d0a2

The problem with that is:

- Creating GIFs out of videos takes a lot of time and effort
- I saw no significant decrease of CPU usage when I tried it
- Supporting multiple screen sizes is a total pain with this approach (at least when I tried - with Autolayout and Size Classes enabled - I couldn't get the GIF to scale correctly across devices)
- Quality of video is poor

Comment: The file size for gif is higher than the video also. I'm interested in a solution too.

Comment: This fellow has an interesting method: https://medium.com/swift-programming/ios-make-an-awesome-video-background-view-objective-c-swift-318e1d71d0a2

Comment: Read the question before you post, I already tried that @DavidDelMonte

Answer (score 21):

Best way is to use `AVFoundation` then you control the video layer itself

In header file declare `@property (nonatomic, strong) AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer;`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
      [super viewDidLoad];


      [self.view.layer addSublayer:self.playerLayer];

      // loop movie
      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                             selector: @selector(replayMovie:)
                                             name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification 
                                             object:nil];
}
-(AVPlayerLayer*)playerLayer{
      if(!_playerLayer){

         // find movie file
         NSString *moviePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"arenaVideo" ofType:@"mp4"];
         NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath];
         _playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:[[AVPlayer alloc]initWithURL:movieURL]];
         _playerLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
         [_playerLayer.player play];

      }
    return _playerLayer
}
-(void)replayMovie:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [self.playerLayer.player play];
}
```

Swift 2.0

```
lazy var playerLayer:AVPlayerLayer = {

    let player = AVPlayer(URL:  NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("LaunchMovie", ofType: "mov")!))
    player.muted = true
    player.allowsExternalPlayback = false
    player.appliesMediaSelectionCriteriaAutomatically = false
    var error:NSError?

    // This is needed so it would not cut off users audio (if listening to music etc.
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient)
    } catch var error1 as NSError {
        error = error1
    } catch {
        fatalError()
    }
    if error != nil {
        print(error)
    }

    var playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer.frame = self.view.frame
    playerLayer.videoGravity = "AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill"
    playerLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    player.play()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:"playerDidReachEnd", name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object:nil)
    return playerLayer
    }()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(self.playerLayer)
}
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}
// If orientation changes
override func willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation(toInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, duration: NSTimeInterval) {
    playerLayer.frame = self.view.frame
}
func playerDidReachEnd(){
    self.playerLayer.player!.seekToTime(kCMTimeZero)
    self.playerLayer.player!.play()

}
```

Tested on iOS7 - iOS9

Comment: @EricAlford why not ?

Comment: Reset time in the delegate method:
 [playerLayer.player seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
 [playerLayer.player play];

Comment: It crash when I implement it

Answer (score 2):

I realize that this is an old post but being that I have had some experience bringing down the CPU usage in my iOS app, I'll respond.

first place to look is use [AVFoundationFramework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationFramework/)

Implementing [AVPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVPlayer) should help bring down the CPU a little

but the best solution is to use Brad Larson's [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) library which utilizes OpenGl and will reduce the CPU usage greatly.  Download the library and there are examples of how to use.  I recommend using GPUImageMovieWriter

Answer (score 1):

I found [this code on GitHub](https://github.com/kschaller/ios-video-background-objective-c/blob/master/Video%20Background/ViewController.m) that worked for me in iOS8/9

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Load the video from the app bundle.
    NSURL *videoURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"video" withExtension:@"mov"];

    // Create and configure the movie player.
    self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];

    self.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    self.moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;

    self.moviePlayer.view.frame = self.view.frame;
    [self.view insertSubview:self.moviePlayer.view atIndex:0];

    [self.moviePlayer play];

    // Loop video.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(loopVideo) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:self.moviePlayer];
}

- (void)loopVideo {
    [self.moviePlayer play];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I do it with a AVAssetReader,GLKView and render through a CIImage pipeline.
When playing none filtered video on simulator, it eat about 80% cpu.
On real device, it cost 1x% with real time filtering(CIFilter). It can be set to loop and control the FPS as well. I've made it on Github and welcome anyone to have a copy. It will be a good alternative choice for someone don't want to drop the whole GPUImage for just a video background view.
Drag and drop the view and it work.
https://github.com/matthewlui/FSVideoView

Answer (score 0):

For iOS9, I used Andrius' code and added the following for the loop:

```
-(void)replayBG:(NSNotification *)n {
    [playerLayer.player seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
    [playerLayer.player play];
}
```