# Objective C - Animation as background gets out of memory error

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an animation with around 500 frames that I would like to play every so often. The animation would be the background, so it would cover the screen but be behind all other elements. A frame would show as the background, but at certain points, the animation would play. The problem I'm running into is that when I use .png files and load them into a UIImage animation a la http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-animation-uiimageview/, I get an out of memory error. The files are small .png files but have large resolution, so I'm assuming they get decompressed into something too large for the device to handle. Is there another way I can play this animation?

Comment: Convert the sequence of PNGs to a movie, and play that movie?

Comment: How can I play a movie behind elements and not open a fullscreen player on top of all the elements?

Comment: Quite a few options described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26571806/most-effective-method-for-video-as-background-in-ios

Comment: You simply cannot load all that animation data at one time, you need a different approach, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/36343926/763355

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in comments above, I would recommend converting the sequence of PNGs to a movie (using `ffmpeg` for instance), then playing the movie directly.

You'll find several options on how to play the movie in the background in this question:
[Most effective method for video as background in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26571806/most-effective-method-for-video-as-background-in-ios)